# Is using iFrame bad practice?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, iframe

I have a node.js express server, `localhost:2000` which serves the entire client's content (html, js, images, ect). The only way I figured to connect to this server using Cordova (mobile app) and my domain is to use `<iframe>`, which seems a bit too good to be true since it does the job. Is there a right way of connecting to the server, or is this method fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method. You can also create a subdomain and redirect it to the ip port you specified. I usually create subdomains.

Comment: Does it impact the performance of the app/browser? Or does it run normal as if `<iframe>` was never used?

Comment: I've used iframe before and didn't have any problems.